# T-SQL Update else Insert stored procedure with Rank() Partition function (SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, rank

I have a stored procedure that partitions by date and then ranks one field for each date. This has been tested and works correctly. The current stored procedure DELETEs the rows if they exists, then just does an INSERT. I would like to turn this into a stored procedure that UPDATES if the row exists else INSERTS a new value. I have looked at many of the posting regarding *Update else Insert* but have not been able to get the correct update syntax.

the table definition is

```
   (@SeriesID   smallint,
    @SymbolID   smallint,
    @Date       smalldatetime,
    @Val        real)
```

The stored procedure I wish to turn into a UPDATE else INSERT is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RankPerDate] 
        @StartDate  smallDateTime,
        @EndDate    smallDateTime,
        @SeriesToRankID smallint,
        @RankedSerieID  smallint
AS
    -- remove time series if it exists
    BEGIN
     DELETE FROM SeriesFloat
     WHERE SeriesID = @RankedSerieID AND (Date >= @StartDate) AND (Date <= @EndDate)    
    END

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO SeriesFloat
        SELECT SeriesID = @RankedSerieID, SymbolID, Date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Val DESC) AS Val
        FROM SeriesFloat 
        WHERE (SeriesID = @SeriesToRankID)  AND (Date >= @StartDate) AND (Date <= @EndDate)
    END
```

The Stored procedure sample inputs:

```
 -- sample values for testing & parameters for stored procedure     
@StartDate = '1999-01-08 00:00:00';
@EndDate   = '1999-01-09 00:00:00';
@SeriesToRankID = 12; -- id of the series that is to be ranked
@RankedSerieID  = 35; -- id of the series that is to be updated/inserted
```

Sample Table data prior to query:

```
SeriesID    SymbolID  Date                  Val
12          2011      1999-01-08 00:00:00   4215000
12          2012      1999-01-08 00:00:00   3215580
12          2013      1999-01-08 00:00:00   2029895
12          2011      1999-01-09 00:00:00   2029895
12          2012      1999-01-09 00:00:00   3395788
12          2013      1999-01-09 00:00:00   4029895
35          2012      1999-01-09 00:00:00   4 -- this row will be updated
35          2013      1999-01-09 00:00:00   8 -- this row will be updated
```

Results of ranking:

```
SeriesID    SymbolID  Date                  Val
35          2011      1999-01-08 00:00:00   1 -- this row is inserted
35          2012      1999-01-08 00:00:00   2 -- this row is inserted
35          2013      1999-01-08 00:00:00   3 -- this row is inserted
35          2011      1999-01-09 00:00:00   3 -- this row is inserted
35          2012      1999-01-09 00:00:00   2 -- this row is updated
35          2013      1999-01-09 00:00:00   1 -- this row is updated
```

Sample Table data after stored procedure in run:

```
SeriesID    SymbolID  Date                  Val
12          2011      1999-01-08 00:00:00   4215000
12          2012      1999-01-08 00:00:00   3215580
12          2013      1999-01-08 00:00:00   2029895
12          2011      1999-01-09 00:00:00   4029895
12          2012      1999-01-09 00:00:00   3395788
12          2013      1999-01-09 00:00:00   2029895
35          2011      1999-01-08 00:00:00   1 -- this row was inserted
35          2012      1999-01-08 00:00:00   2 -- this row was inserted
35          2013      1999-01-08 00:00:00   3 -- this row was inserted
35          2011      1999-01-09 00:00:00   3 -- this row was inserted
35          2012      1999-01-09 00:00:00   2 -- this row was updated
35          2013      1999-01-09 00:00:00   1 -- this row was updated
```

Can anyone provide an example of how this is done?

Comment: Why is @SeriesID = 12 and @OutputID = 35? Later you say SELECT SeriesID = @OutputID ... WHERE SeriesID = @SeriesID. Typo, intentional confusion, something in between? Also, can you please specify and/or tag whether you are using Microsoft SQL Server (tag = sql-server) and what version you are using (e.g. sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008) - as the solution may take advantage of features that aren't in all versions.

Comment: Using  sql-server-2008 (added TAG)

Comment: SeriesID is the id of the series that is to be ranked. It is one of the inputs for the stored procedure.

Comment: @OutputID is also a parameter for the stored procedure. It is the ID of the Ranked series. Once the ranking per date has been done, it shodl insert with the seriesID equal to the @outputID

Comment: So @OutputID is an input parameter? And it is not the same as @SeriesID? Do you see why this is confusing? Where does val come from? And SymbolID? I don't see these being supplied as parameters.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you showed some data in the table before and after the insert/update. This will make it much easier to determine what your actual goal is.

Comment: I can see how the use of @SeriesId is confusing. I have edited it to make it more explicit

Comment: Val and SymbolID are fields in the table.

Comment: Yes I got that, for an update. But if we are inserting a NEW ROW because it doesn't already exist, where do the values for val and Symbol come from?

Comment: Like I said, instead of trying to make things more explicit with the use of still confusing variable names, and going back and forth with narrative and describing the word problem in different ways, can you show sample data in the table before and after an update/insert? I think a lot of my questions will be answered if you do that.

Comment: Thanks, but can you also include a case where the row did not exist first? e.g. there should be 4 or 5 rows before the operation, not 6, so that at least one insert has to take place. This was the whole point of your question, right? This will also help illustrate why I want to know where SymbolID comes from.

Comment: Just to be clear, an update is necessary when there exists a row with the same SeriesID, SymbolID, and Date. If this case we just update Val. Otherwise we insert SeriesID, SymbolID, Date, and Val

Comment: Added examples of where they are updated and where they are inserted. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What "same SymbolID"? You are not passing SymbolID in as a parameter, so how do you know whether such a row already exists? WHERE SymbolID = ?????????????????

Comment: `WHERE (SeriesID = @SeriesToRankID)`  @SeriesToRankID is the parameter I pass in to determine whether it exists

Comment: I give up, sorry. I am not sure how else to help you define the problem better - I have no idea how to match on SeriesID, SymbolID and Date when you are only supplying SeriesID and Date as parameters. Maybe someone else will have better luck.

Comment: `UPDATE SeriesFloat SET Val = @Val WHERE SeriesID = @SeriesToRankID AND SymbolID = @SymbolID AND(Date >= @StartDate) AND (Date <= @EndDate)
 ELSE
  INSERT INTO SeriesFloat VALUES(@SeriesID, @SymbolID, @Date, @Val)`

Comment: So now there *is* a @SymbolID parameter? I've asked where this came from multiple times - are you appreciating my frustration now?

Comment: I still don't see how this solves the problem. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you always want three rows per SeriesID - one with SymbolID 2011, one with SymbolID 2012, one with SymbolID 2013. Is this a fair assumption? Otherwise please explain what value was given for SymbolID to transform the data using the stored procedure and your sample data above.

Comment: If you think of this as a two step procedure it may become clearer. Step 1: Create a table of ranked value as per the second output example above. Step2 - if a row wit the same SeriesId, SymbolId, and Date exist, update the Val, otherwise insert. The SymbolId is therefore one of the values in the temporary output.

Comment: Another way to do this is. `Delete from Seriesfloat where SeriesID = RankedSerieID AND (Date >= @StartDate) AND (Date <= @EndDate)   GO INSERT INTO Seriesfloat` .... (the example functions output)

Comment: Ok, and why are the inputs 2011-06-22 and 2011-06-24? The sample data is 1999-01-08 and 1999-01-09, so your parameters still do not match. How does the range affect the impact on the table - if the range is larger (e.g. 3 days), do you add a set of rows for each date in the range?

Comment: Is answer to your question, Yes three rows per series.

Comment: Because I cut and pasted from my DB and forgot to edit them :-| Edited

Comment: "if the range is larger (e.g. 3 days), do you add a set of rows for each date in the range?"<- Yes.

Comment: -1 for not asking correct question. God knows what folk expect us to do with partial information

Comment: @gbn I think it might be a record. I doubt Andre has any teeth left.

Comment: I'm scarred for life. Usually, I try to provide a complete post. Evidently, I missed the mark on this one. Since I care, I'll ask... Is it still missing information?

Comment: Yes, it is still missing information. You haven't described exactly how the new Val is based on the old Val. In your sample output, the Val seems to be applied arbitrarily. Can you walk through exactly how 4 and 8 because 2 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

After all the teeth pulling, here is what I came up with. Your `ORDER BY Val` within the `RANK() OVER()` clause didn't make sense (since the Val is just the ranking and gets re-assigned). Based on your sample output I guessed that this ranking should be determined by SymbolID.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SeriesFloat') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.SeriesFloat;
GO

-- suggest using DATE since you don't care about time
-- also does the Val column really need to be REAL?
-- could probably be an INT.

CREATE TABLE dbo.SeriesFloat
(
    SeriesID   SMALLINT,
    SymbolID   SMALLINT,
    [Date]     SMALLDATETIME,
    Val        REAL
);

INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2011, '1999-01-08', 4215000;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2012, '1999-01-08', 3215580;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2013, '1999-01-08', 2029895;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2011, '1999-01-09', 4029895;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2012, '1999-01-09', 3395788;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 12, 2013, '1999-01-09', 2029895;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 35, 2012, '1999-01-09', 4;
INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat SELECT 35, 2013, '1999-01-09', 8;

-- change these two params to test larger ranges (up to 2,048 days):

DECLARE @Start DATE = '1999-01-08',
        @End   DATE = '1999-01-09',
        @SeriesToRankID SMALLINT = 12,
        @RankedSerieID  SMALLINT = 35;

-- let's figure out the set of days - good for a range up to 2,048 days
-- if you need more than that, build a table of numbers

DECLARE @DaysInRange TABLE
(
    d DATE
);

INSERT @DaysInRange
    SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, number, @Start)
        FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
        WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End);

-- let's insert the rows that don't yet exist

INSERT dbo.SeriesFloat(SeriesID, SymbolID, [Date])
SELECT DISTINCT SeriesID = @RankedSerieID, s.SymbolID, d.d
    FROM dbo.SeriesFloat AS s 
    CROSS JOIN @DaysInRange AS d
    WHERE s.SeriesID = @SeriesToRankID
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SeriesFloat 
            WHERE SeriesID = @RankedSerieID
            AND [Date] = d.d
            AND SymbolID = s.SymbolID
    );

-- then update all of them with ranking

WITH s AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SeriesID, SymbolID, [Date],
        Val = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY SymbolID)
    FROM 
        dbo.SeriesFloat
    WHERE 
        SeriesID = @RankedSerieID
)
UPDATE sf SET Val = s.Val
    FROM dbo.SeriesFloat AS sf
    INNER JOIN s 
        ON sf.SymbolID = s.SymbolID
        AND sf.[Date] = s.[Date]
    WHERE sf.SeriesID = @RankedSerieID;

SELECT SeriesID, SymbolID, [Date], Val
    FROM dbo.SeriesFloat 
    ORDER BY SeriesID, [Date], Val;
GO
```

I was not interested in trying MERGE to solve this problem, but you can check out the docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(SQL.100).aspx

As an aside, why do you need to store the Val ranking? Seems like you will always be able to generate this at query time (using a view if you use that column a lot).

Comment: Thanks for this. The val in this case can by INT but this table mostly holds values that need a real type. Ditto for Date.

Comment: Had time to run this. Not the solution as the rank is based on Val not SymbolID. Please don't spend any more time on this. My delete and insert (stored procedure in my original question) works even though it is not ideal.

Comment: Your description does not make sense based on the sample data you provided. The SymbolID/Val for the two rows where SeriesID = 35 were 2012/4 and 2013/8 respectively. Yet in the output you've changed it so that the Val that gets assigned to these rows is 2 and 1. How are 2 and 1 based on 4 and 8?